# I want to enforce n seconds of delay between user posts in a PHP application, how can I do this?

Tags: php, post

I want to prevent users (different clients) from posting data at the "same" time, I need them to wait n seconds after the last POST. Would some sort of server-side delay achieve this?

How does a PHP server attend clients? Is it one by one or at the same time?

Comment: You could store the post time in a session and only accept new posts if there is a certain minimum time difference. You can start here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: `php` is generally severed by an `HTTP` server such as `apache` which turns runs the script once for every `HTTP` request. As @jeroen mentioned you could store access time in `$_SESSION` using http://php.net/microtime . make sure to pass `true` like `$_SESSION['lastaccess'] = microtime(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a timestamp in the session, plant a cookie, or store a timestamp in a database.

Session is probably the easiest, fastest and least invasive.

```
// 3600 seconds is 1 hour.
if ($_SESSION['last_post'] < time() + 3600)
{
  //cannot post
  return false;
}

// post comment.
$_SESSION['last_post'] = time();
return true
```

To apply to all users as a global effect use an apc cache entry or a database flag.

```
// 3600 seconds is 1 hour.
if (apc_fetch('comment_timeout' < time() + 3600)
{
  //cannot post
  return false;
}

// post comment.
apc_add('comment_timeout' , time());
return true
```

Comment: This looks useful but I believe it only applies to each user individually. I want to prevent two different clients to post n seconds after the other one(s)

Comment: If you want data that is persistent and spans multiple sessions you need to use a database of some sort. You can use the same code but instead of session use an apc cache entry.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay applies to all users, you would need to store a timestamp of the last post using some form of persistence, then check that value before each new post to see if the appropriate amount of time has elapsed. Options would be storing the value in a **database**, in a **cache** (like memcached), or simply in a **file**.

Since you already have a database (presumably), adding a table in which you store the timestamp (and any other config-type variables that you might need) is probably the simplest option.

A cache would be overkill if it's only used for storing one value.

If you don't want to use a database for this, then it's simple enough to store the timestamp in a file, using `file_put_contents`, and retrieve it with `file_get_contents`. (PHP's session information is stored in files in much the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if ((time() - $_SESSION['last_post_time']) < 60)
{
    // user posted within 60 seconds
}
else
{
    //process data as normal

    // reset last post time
    $_SESSION['last_post_time'] = time();
}
```

However, a user could get around this by closing down their browser, so are you using a database? If so, store the last post time in the database linked to IP and perform the same check as above.

Comment: This applies to each user individually. I want to prevent two different clients to post n seconds after the other, would you suggest using the DB to keep track of this like some sort of "semaphore".

Answer (score 0):

I don't really deal with PHP, so I can't give you a "real" answer.  But I think it might be better to dispatch to a worker.

So with Python/Celery, which is generally what I work with (NOTE: I am not slighting PHP; no flamewar), I would use `apply_async(<some function>, delay=<N seconds>)`. Celery is a worker queue that here is just accepting a job, to complete the post in this case.

That pattern would let you send the job on its way, delayed in the appropriate way, and won't necessarily block your server processes.